# How can I import a non standard package in python on mac? This package does not support pip install

Tags: python, shell, command-line, package

I used to work with windows when I install a non basic python package with the cmd, but I dont know how to do it on mac, this packaged cant use pip to install on the terminal

Answer (score 0):

It really depends a lot on the specific package. The options can be different, let me present you some:

- You can simply add the source files (if they are not properly packaged) to your project and import them
- In the same scenario, if the script is not packaged, you can check if there is a way to install it (read the docs). A common way to do it is by having a script in root called *setup.py*. Try to see if there is a setup script or read the docs to see if there is a way to install it
- Check if the package can not be installed with another general package management (you mentioned you use a mac so check with [homebrew](https://brew.sh))
- Another possible package management tool for Python is [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo), check that one too

Hope this helps!